# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString function

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I am new to ios development.

```
NSString *newString2 = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"1," withString:@""];
```

My problem is i do not know how to check for any number i.e. `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"anyInt,`" where any Int is any `integer` number from 1 to N.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why to check, just replace, if it will be there it will b replaced

Comment: because i have some data coming as 0,0 .. so i need to check. Replacement should be done only if there is any no greater than 0.

Comment: @user2885928: Can you give a concrete example of an input string and output string, that shows exactly what should be replaced and what should not be replaced?

Comment: for String 1,10 : i need to show only 10
and for String 0,0 : i need to show "--" 

For nos in first part greater than 0, second part is shown. For 0 in first part, -- is shown.

Comment: Ur question is bit ambiguous.Please elaborate exactly what u r trying to achieve. @user2885928

Comment: I need to check for string "anyNo," where anyNo > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For nos in first part greater than 0, second part is shown. For 0 in first part, -- is shown.*

Try the below code,

```
NSString * aString = @"1,10";
NSString *newString2;
NSArray *items = [aString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

if([[items objectAtIndex:0] integerValue]>0)
  newString2 = [items objectAtIndex:1];
else
    newString2 = @"--";
```

Comment: what is the input string that you are passing?

Answer (score 3):

Using regular expressions is the best solution:

```
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[1-9]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

Check official [NSRegularExpression documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there is also a good tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/)

Answer (score 3):

A regular expression is probably the easiest solution. Whether you want to remove just single digits or multiple digits, a regular expression can help.

```
NSString *aString = @"Apple 10, Banana 3, Carrot 5, Durian 42, Eggplant 4,";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[0-9]+," options:0 error:NULL];    
NSString *newString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:aString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [aString length]) withTemplate:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", newString);

// result should be "Apple  Banana  Carrot  Durian  Eggplant "
```

Regular expressions may seem overwhelming or difficult to understand at first, but it is only because they can be very powerful for searching and replacing text. Have a look at the [overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW52) section of the NSRegularExpression documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Just these two lines to remove all numbers from a string.

```
 NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet 
    characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

 NSString *newString = [[tempstr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: numbers] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the range and then you want to replace then use below api:-

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

Answer (score 0):

why you want to check the existence of the Integer because ultimate you'll replace it with `''`. So just use the below line

```
NSString *newString2 = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString StringWithFormat:@"%d", anyInt], withString:@""];
```

Above line will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: i don't know what will the last no in anyInt.. How to define a range for it.. 1 to infinity?

Comment: what is anyInt here ?

Comment: Check the question, anyInt is any integer number from 1 to N.